# Change language of bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, languages

I'm currently writing my master thesis with Texstudio and for this I'm using a template the chair handed to me. The template is in german, but I'm asked to write in english, so I adjusted it to the best of my knowledge, but somehow I can't change the language of the bibliography to english. The header 'bibliography' changed to english, but all references in it are given in german, like the abbrevations Nr. and S. for number and page. Further, all the citations in the body are in german, like Author u. a. instead of Author et al..

This is my vorlage.tex (vorlage in english = template)

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\include{header}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{0}

% Titelblatt
\include{titel}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\roman{page}}
\setcounter{page}{1}

\include{Erklaerung}
\include{synopsis}

% Inhaltsverzeichnis
\tableofcontents

\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}
\setcounter{page}{1}

\include{Einleitung}
\include{Kap2}
\include{Kap3}
\include{Kap4}
\include{Ergebnisse}
\include{Fazit}

% Erzeugung von Verzeichnissen %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\listoftables           % Tabellenverzeichnis
\listofalgorithms       % Algorithmenverzeichnis
\listoffigures          % Abbildungsverzeichnis
\printnomenclature      % Symbolverzeichnis

% Literaturverzeichnis
\bibliographystyle{natdin}
\bibliography{literatur}

%\bibliographystyle{alpha}

% Index
%\printindex

\end{document}
```

and this my header.tex

```
% Pakete f\"{u}r deutsche Sprachunterst\"{u}tzung
%\usepackage{ucs}            % Eventuell benoetigt
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % F\"{u}r Systeme die Unicode benutzen
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}  % bei Systemen mit Windows
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}

% Aktiviert die Rechschreibprï¿œfung auf deutsch, man kann
% auch mehrere Sprachen einbinden, falls der Text mehr-
% sprachig sein soll
\usepackage[english]{babel}

% Umlaute werden als ein Zeichen gesetzt
% es gibt die Option OT1 und T1, wobei T1 doppelt so viele
% Zeichen hat wie OT1 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{ragged2e}

% Erzeugt einen sinnlosen Text
\usepackage{blindtext}

% Aktiviert Textfarben
\usepackage{color}          % im Text
\usepackage{colortbl}       % in Tabellen

% Boxen um Text
\usepackage{framed}

%\usepackage{txfonts}

% Dreht Tabellen
%\usepackage{lscape}

% Pakete f\"{u}r Mathe:
\usepackage{amsfonts,   % erweiterter Schriftenvorrat fuer Mathematiksatz
                        amsmath,    % erweiterte mathematische Konstrukte
                        amsthm,     % Satz- und Beweisumgebung
                        amscd,      
                        amssymb,    % zusaetzliche mathematische Symbole
                        array}      
\usepackage{nicefrac}

% Pakete fï¿œr Pseudocode
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage[english,                    % deutsche Wï¿œrter (Algorithmus)
                        %boxruled,          % eingerahmt + Titel extra eingerahmt
                        ruled,                  % nur horizontale Striche zur Abgrenzung
                        algochapter,        % Numerierung wie Kapitel
                        lined,                  % \SetLine ist default
                        linesnumbered,  % Zeilennumerierung
                        longend                 % ausfï¿œhrliche Beendung des Blocks endif statt end
                        %dotocloa               % Algorithmenliste im Inhlatsverzeichnis
                        ]{algorithm2e}

% Um pdf-Dokumente in Latex einzubinden
\usepackage{pdfpages}

% Um Bilder (.eps Graphiken) einzufï¿œgen
% alternativ graphics
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
% Verschiedene Pakete um Tabellen zu manipulieren
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{lastpage}              % Referenz auf Seitenzahl durch \pageref{LastPage}
\usepackage{dsfont}                % Mengensymbole mit Doppelstrich
\usepackage{enumerate}             % fuer flexiblere Nummerierungen
\usepackage{wasysym}               % u. a. fuer das Widerspruchssymbol
%\usepackage{mbboard}                    % erweiterte Blackbord Bold Symbole

% Festlegung der Seitenraender
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{includeheadfoot,bottom=2cm,top=2cm,right=3cm,left=3cm}

% Festlegung der Kopf- und Fusseile
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
%\lhead{links oben}
%\chead{mitte oben}
\rhead{}
%\lfoot{links unten}
\cfoot{\thepage} % mitte unten
%\rfoot{rechts unten}

% Ein Abkï¿œrzungsverzeichnis anzulegen
\usepackage[english]{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

% Ein Sachregister erstellen
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
% Literaturverzeichnis
\usepackage{natbib}

% Verlinken von Internetseiten
\usepackage{url}

% Verlinkung des Inhaltverzeichniss
% muss als letztes geladen werden.
%\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0},                     % verhindert sï¿œmtliche Umrandungen, die referenziert werden.
%                       linktocpage = false,                % Seitenzahlen in allen Verzeichnissen werden als Sprungmarke genutzt (true)
%                       colorlinks = false,                 % Sprungmarken werden je nach Art eingefï¿œrbt (true)
%                       hyperfigures = true,                % Abbildungen kï¿œnnen als Sprungmarke benutzt werden
%                       hyperfootnotes = true,          % Fuï¿œnoten kï¿œnnen als Sprungmarke benutzt werden
%                       hyperindex = true,                  % Indizes kï¿œnnen als Sprungmarke benutzt werden
%                       bookmarks = false,                  % es gibt keine Lesezeichenansicht
%                       pdfstartview = FitV,            % passt die Startgrï¿œï¿œe des Fensters an (Fit = Seitenanpassung, FitV = Hï¿œhe, FitH = Breite)
%                       ngerman,                                        % Gibt die deutschen Begriffe aus, z.b. bei \autoref{}
%                       pdftitle = {},                          % Setzt den Titel des Dokuments
%                       pdfauthor={},                               % Setzt den Autoren
%                       pdfkeywords={},                         % Setzt Schlagworte fï¿œr das Dokument                  
%                       pdfpagemode={UseOutlines}       % Definiert wie das Dokument geï¿œffnet wird                        
%                       ]{hyperref}  
%
\usepackage[english,                                        % Gibt die deutschen Begriffe aus, z.b. bei \autoref{}
                     ]{hyperref}

      

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm} % verhindert Einruecken der ersten Zeile im Abschnitt

%\swapnumbers           %  Nummerrierung links
\renewcommand{\proofname}{Beweis}                           % ï¿œndert den Beweisnamen



\newtheoremstyle{satz}{\topsep}{\topsep}
    {\itshape}                                                                      % Body font
    {}                                                                                      % Indent amount (empty = no indent, \parindent = para indent)
    {\bfseries}                                                                     % Thm head font
    {:}                                                                                     % Punctuation after thm head
    {\newline}                                                                      % Space after thm head (\newline = linebreak)
    {\thmnumber{(#2)}\thmname{ #1}\thmnote{ #3}}    % Thm head spec
\theoremstyle{satz}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{satz}[lemma]{Satz}
\newtheorem{folg}[lemma]{Folgerung}
\newtheorem{kor}[lemma]{Korollar}

\newtheoremstyle{definition}{\topsep}{\topsep}
  {}                                                                                        % Body font
    {}                                                                                      % Indent amount (empty = no indent, \parindent = para indent)        
    {\bfseries}                                                                     % Thm head font
    {:}                                                                                     % Punctuation after thm head
    {\newline}                                                                      % Space after thm head (\newline = linebreak)
    {\thmnumber{(#2)}\thmname{ #1}\thmnote{ #3}}    % Thm head spec
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[lemma]{Definition}
\newtheorem{bsp}[lemma]{Beispiel}
\newtheorem*{*bsp}{Beispiel}
\newtheorem{bspe}[lemma]{Beispiele}
\newtheorem{bem}[lemma]{Bemerkung}
\newtheorem{bemn}[lemma]{Bemerkungen}
\newtheorem{bez}[lemma]{Bezeichnungen}
\newtheorem{bew}[lemma]{Beweis}
\newtheorem{bidee}[lemma]{Beweisidee}

% Aendern der Symbole f\"{u}r enumerate-Umgebungen
%\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{(\roman{enumi})}

% neue Shortcuts
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}     % Mengensymbole
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}
\newcommand \0 {\textbf{0}}
\newcommand \1 {\textbf{1}}
\newcommand \id {\mbox{id}}
\newcommand \GL{\mbox{GL}}
\newcommand{\dcup}{\stackrel{\centerdot}{\cup}}  % disjunkte Vereinigung
\DeclareMathOperator{\Ker}{Ker}
\DeclareMathOperator{\End}{End}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Aut}{Aut}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Grad}{Grad}
\DeclareMathOperator{\diag}{diag}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Spur}{Spur}
%\newcommand \Vor {\textbf{Voraussetzung }}
%\newcommand \Beh {\textbf{Behauptung }}
%\newcommand \Ann {\textbf{Annahme }}
%\newcommand \Bew {\textbf{Beweis }}
\newcommand{\Qed}{\hfill \qedsymbol}    % Setzt Beweisabschlusszeichen ans Ende der Zeile

\newcommand{\rk}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}  % Klammern in angepasster Groesse
\newcommand{\ek}[1]{\left[ #1 \right]}
\newcommand{\gk}[1]{\left\{ #1 \right\}}
\newcommand{\sk}[1]{\left< #1 \right>}

\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}    % Betrag
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\lVert#1\rVert}   % Norm
\newcommand{\Sum}{\displaystyle \sum}   % fuer grosse Summenzeichen auch in $...$
\newcommand{\ksum}{\textstyle \sum}     % fuer kleine Summenzeichen auch in \[...\]
\newcommand{\Frac}{\displaystyle \frac}
\newcommand{\kfrac}{\textstyle \frac}

\newcommand{\imp}{\Rightarrow}              % Pfeile
\newcommand{\aeq}{\Leftrightarrow}

\newcommand{\gw}[1][n]{\underset{#1 \to \infty}{\lim}}  % Grenzwertsymbole
\newcommand{\kgt}[1][n]{\underset{#1 \to \infty}{\longrightarrow}}

\newcommand{\rd}{\textcolor{red}}

% Ermï¿œglicht das Referenzieren auf Pseudocode mit Hilfe von
% hyperref und algorithm
\newcommand{\theHalgorithm}{\arabic{algorithm}}

% Umdefinition bereits vorhandener Befehle
\renewcommand{\phi}{\varphi}
\renewcommand{\epsilon}{\varepsilon}
\renewcommand{\*}{\cdot}
%\renewcommand{\leq}{\leqslant} % Kleiner/gleich-Zeichen mit schraegem Strich
%\renewcommand{\geq}{\geqslant}

%\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\begin{turn}{90}\begin{minipage}{#1}\scriptsize \raggedright \hspace {0pt}}l <{\end{minipage}\end{turn}}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\begin{turn}{90}\begin{minipage}{#1}\scriptsize \raggedright \hspace {0pt}}l <{\end{minipage}\end{turn}}}

% Gleichungsnummern sind Kapitelabhï¿œngig 
% Im Kapitel 1 ist dann die Nummerierung (1.1) (1.2) usw.
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
%\numberwithin{algorithm}{section}
```

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, I would always avoid using handed-down templates such as these. This one in particular looks like it was written many (many) years ago and includes some packages that are more or less deprecated today, e.g. `color` or `inputenc` (especially with `latin9`). Also you shouldn't use `fancyhdr` in a KOMA-class document. My suggestion would be to start from scratch, identify the packages and definitions you personally need and start your document from there making sure you knwo why you add a package and what it does.

Comment: Can you change from bibtex to biblatex/biber? Then language is no problem ...